# Azure IoT C SDK: IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendTelemetryAsync vs IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendEventAsync

Tags: c, azure-iot-hub

I'm starting to work with the Azure IoT C SDK. Currently, I am experimenting with the different ways to transmit data between a device and the cloud.

What is the difference between IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendTelemetryAsync and IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendEventAsync?

The documentation doesn't really help as it doesn't state what the difference between telemetry data and an event is.

The log output looks the very same for both calls:

```
-> 08:14:54 PUBLISH | IS_DUP: false | RETAIN: 0 | QOS: DELIVER_AT_LEAST_ONCE | TOPIC_NAME: devices/Test1/messages/events/ | PACKET_ID: 5 | PAYLOAD_LEN: 9
-> 08:14:54 PUBLISH | IS_DUP: false | RETAIN: 0 | QOS: DELIVER_AT_LEAST_ONCE | TOPIC_NAME: devices/Test1/messages/events/ | PACKET_ID: 6 | PAYLOAD_LEN: 9
```

A google search doesn't turn up any information either.

Comment: refer this for [Cloud-to-device](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance.md) and  [Device-to-cloud](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-d2c-guidance.md)

Comment: `SendTelemetryAsync ` Sends an event to the IoT [hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.iothubmoduleclient.sendtelemetryasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview) and IotHubModuleClient instance must be opened already. `SendEventAsync ` Sends an event to a [hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient.sendeventasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendEventAsync is used to send non-telemetry events to the IoT [hub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-non-telemetry-event-schema.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendTelemetryAsync is simply an alias for IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendEventAsync. They do the same thing. See the code here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/59b7663bb329b64103bb0f22d95162087c01037c/iothub_client/src/iothub_device_client_ll.c#L171

Comment: That just leaves the question: Why? What's the point?